# How to combine callLater and addCallback?

Tags: python, twisted

This is so broken, I hope you are merciful with me:

```
reactor.callLater(0, myFunction, parameter1).addCallback(reactor.stop)
reactor.run()
```

`myFunction` returns a deferred.

I hope it is clear what I want to do:

- as soon as the reactor is running, I want to call `myFunction`. That is why I am using 0 as the delay parameter. Is there no other way except callLater? It looks funny to pass it a delay of 0.
- I want to stop the reactor as soon as `myFunction` has completed the task.

The problems that I have so far:

- `AttributeError: DelayedCall instance has no attribute 'addCallback'`. Fair enough! How do I put a callback in the callback chain started by `myFunction` then?
- `exceptions.TypeError: stop() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`.

To solve the second problem I had to define a special function:

```
def stopReactor(result):
    gd.log.info( 'Result: %s' % result)
    gd.log.info( 'Stopping reactor immediatelly' )
    reactor.stop()
```

And change the code to:

```
reactor.callLater(0, myFunction, parameter1).addCallback(stopReactor)
reactor.run()
```

(still not working because of the callLater problem, but `stopReactor` will work now)

Is there really no other way to call `reactor.stop` except by defining an extra function?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`IReactorTime.callLater` and `Deferred` are mixed together by `twisted.internet.task.deferLater`.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, task

d = task.deferLater(reactor, 0, myFunction, parameter1)
d.addCallback(lambda ignored: reactor.stop())
reactor.run()
```

Comment: I find this option very readable. The `lambda ignored` bit looks magic to me: could you clarify what it exactly does?

Comment: Callbacks on a Deferred are called with an argument.  `reactor.stop` does not take any arguments.  `lambda ignored: reactor.stop()` accepts and argument, ignores it, and calls `reactor.stop` with no arguments.

Comment: It would be a bit more conventional to write: 'lambda _: reactor.stop'

Comment: "ignored" has an obvious meaning, and if it isn't obvious to someone, then it is discoverable.  "\_" is non-obvious and non-discoverable (and hard to type into a stackoverflow comment box!).  It is strictly worse for readability.  However, I see that other folks have already approved an edit to my answer which replaced "ignored" with "_". And who am I to argue?

Comment: then how about _ignored?

Comment: "_" is a python convention for ignored

Answer (score 1):

> I want to stop the reactor as soon as myFunction has completed the task.

So, create a wrapper that does myFunction's work and then stops the reactor?

```
def wrapper(reactor, *args):
    myFunction(*args)
    reactor.stop()

reactor.callLater(0, wrapper, reactor, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the callback to the deferred that myFunction returns, since callLater doesn't return a function. Something like this might work:

```
reactor.callLater(0, lambda: myFunction(parameter1).addCallback(lambda _: reactor.stop())
```

But this is not tested.

You need to write a new function (here the lambda _: reactor.stop()) because callbacks to a deferred always take the result up to then. If you find yourself wanting to use callbacks for their side-effects and you don't care about propagating values often, you could define a little helper function:

```
def ignoringarg(f):
    return lambda _: f()
```

And then do:

```
reactor.callLater(0, lambda: myFunction(paramater1).addCallback(ignoringarg(reactor.stop)))
```

(What would be really neat would be to define an `__rshift__` (and in-place analogue) for the `Deferred` class so you could do: `myFunction(parameter1) >> reactor.stop`, for when you want to abandon the argument, or `myFunction(parameter1) >>= someotherfunc` for when you want to propagate the argument. If you think that abusing haskellish syntax is "neat", anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

If You need to trigger callback with some action, just do it (possibly there's no need to return deferred, or smth).
Just to clarify things (using purely deferreds):

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer

# That will be our deferred to play with
# it has callback and errback methods
d = defer.Deferred()

def my_function(x):
    print 'function', x
    # need to trigger deferred upon function run?
    # Lets tell it to do so:
    d.callback(x)

# That's our callback to run after triggering `d`    
def d_callback(y):
    print 'callback ', y

# now let's bind that callback to be actually launched by `d`
d.addCallback(d_callback)

# now adding another callback just to stop reactor
# note lambda simply helps to agree number of arguments
d.addCallback(lambda data: reactor.stop())

# so we'll call `my_function` in 2 secs, then it runs
# then it triggers `d` to fire its callbacks
# then `d` actually detonates the whole chain of its added callbacks

reactor.callLater(2, my_function, 'asdf') # 'asdf' is some stupid param

# Here how it works
print 'Lets start!'
reactor.run()
print 'Done!'
```