# ReactorNotRestartable when launching two equivalent unittest with twisted and trial

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, twisted, trial

I've two test classes (`TrialTest1` and `TrialTest2`) written in two files (`test_trial1.py` and `test_trial2.py`) mostly identical (the only difference is the class name):

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.trial import unittest


class TrialTest1(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        print("setUp()")

    def test_main(self):
        print("test_main")
        reactor.callLater(1, self._called_by_deffered1)
        reactor.run()

    def _called_by_deffered1(self):
        print("_called_by_deffered1")
        reactor.callLater(1, self._called_by_deffered2)

    def _called_by_deffered2(self):
        print("_called_by_deffered2")
        reactor.stop()

    def tearDown(self):
        print("tearDown()")
```

When I run each test idepently, everything is fine. But when I launch both I've the following output:

```
setUp()
test_main
_called_by_deffered1
_called_by_deffered2
tearDown()
setUp()
test_main
tearDown()

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 137, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/utils.py", line 203, in runWithWarningsSuppressed
    reraise(exc_info[1], exc_info[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/utils.py", line 199, in runWithWarningsSuppressed
    result = f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/kartoch/works/python/netkython/tests/test_twisted_trial2.py", line 13, in test_main
    reactor.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1191, in run
    self.startRunning(installSignalHandlers=installSignalHandlers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1171, in startRunning
    ReactorBase.startRunning(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 683, in startRunning
    raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
ReactorNotRestartable


Error
DirtyReactorAggregateError: Reactor was unclean.
DelayedCalls: (set twisted.internet.base.DelayedCall.debug = True to debug)
<DelayedCall 0x8d6482c [0.98535490036s] called=0 cancelled=0 TrialTest2._called_by_deffered1()>


Process finished with exit code 0
```

It seems the reactor is not switched off correctly after the first test. Does anyone know where is the problem ? It seems `tearDown()` is called to early (before `_called_by_deffered1` in the second test), maybe a fix would be to use [`deferTearDown`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.trial.unittest.TestCase.html#deferTearDown) (not documented method of trial unittest).

#### EDIT

One of the solution proposed was to remove `reactor.run()` and `reactor.stop()` because a reactor is not restartable and you have only one reactor instance for all test by default:

```
class TrialTest1(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        print("setUp()")

    def test_main(self):
        print("test_main")
        reactor.callLater(1, self._called_by_deffered1)

    def _called_by_deffered1(self):
        print("_called_by_deffered1")
        reactor.callLater(1, self._called_by_deffered2)

    def _called_by_deffered2(self):
        print("_called_by_deffered2")

    def tearDown(self):
        print("tearDown()")
```

But when removing calls to such methods, my tests fail without executing `_called_by_deffered` methods:

```
setUp()
test_main
tearDown()

Error
DirtyReactorAggregateError: Reactor was unclean.
DelayedCalls: (set twisted.internet.base.DelayedCall.debug = True to debug)
<DelayedCall 0x94967ec [0.99936413765s] called=0 cancelled=0 TrialTest1._called_by_deffered1()>

setUp()
test_main
tearDown()

Error
DirtyReactorAggregateError: Reactor was unclean.
DelayedCalls: (set twisted.internet.base.DelayedCall.debug = True to debug)
<DelayedCall 0x94968cc [0.99958896637s] called=0 cancelled=0 TrialTest2._called_by_deffered1()>
```

If I want to use only one instance of reactor shared between tests, how  `_called_by_deffered` methods could be part of the test (*i.e.* executed before `tearDown`) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of Jean-Paul, [this page](http://mumak.net/stuff/twisted-disconnect.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174437/how-to-combine-calllater-and-addcallback), I've been able to fix the problem using `twisted.internet.task.deferLater()`. To summarize the point i was looking for: if a test method returning a deferred, the 'tearDown()' method will be called only when all deferreds are fired.

This is the code:

```
from twisted.trial import unittest
from twisted.internet import reactor, task


class TrialTest1(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        print("setUp()")

    def test_main(self):
        print("test_main()")
        return task.deferLater(reactor, 1, self._called_by_deffered1)

    def _called_by_deffered1(self):
        print("_called_by_deffered1()")
        return task.deferLater(reactor, 1, self._called_by_deffered2)

    def _called_by_deffered2(self):
        print("_called_by_deffered2()")

    def tearDown(self):
        print("tearDown()")
```

Output:

```
setUp() 
test_main()

// (1s wait)

_called_by_deffered1()

// (1s wait)

_called_by_deffered2()
tearDown()
```

Comment: I copy-pasted your code to test the output, no output appears. Any idea why?

Answer (score 4):

The reactor is not restartable.  There are two obvious options for your to pursue for writing your tests.

One is to use the global reactor.  trial starts and stops it - your tests never have to call `reactor.run` or `reactor.stop` (and they never should).  It is accessible in the usual way, `from twisted.internet import reactor`.

The other is to use a new reactor instance per test.  There are some test-oriented reactor instances in `twisted.test.proto_helpers` (that is the only part of `twisted.test` that is a public, supported interface by the way).  `MemoryReactor` and `StringTransport` get you most of the way towards being able to test network interactions.  `twisted.internet.task.Clock` helps you out with testing time-based events.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I remove 'reactor.run()' and 'reactor.stop()' from my code source the deferreds is never called, only the `setUp`, `test_main` and `tearDown`. Thus both tests return `DirtyReactorAggregateError: Reactor was unclean` because there is a Deffered not executed. I think I need something like "please execute the `tearDown` after the reactor is clean or only after the execution of `_called_by_deffered2`. Any idea ? I'm completing the question...

Comment: For the second point, thank you to pint me to these interesting functions very helpful to reduce test complexity. But I still need at least one of my tests to cope with a real reactor.