# Scrapy: How to run spider from other python script twice or more？

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, twisted

Scrapy version: 1.0.5

I have searched for long time, but most of workarounds don't work in current Scrapy version.

My spider is defined in jingdong_spider.py, and the interface(learn it by [Scrapy Documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script)) to run spider is below:

```
# interface
def search(keyword):
    configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})
    runner = CrawlerRunner()
    d = runner.crawl(JingdongSpider,keyword)
    d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
    reactor.run() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

Then in temp.py I will call the `search(keyword)` above to run spider.

Now the problem: I called search(keyword) once, and it worked well.But I called it twice, for instance,

in temp.py

```
search('iphone')
search('ipad2')
```

it reported:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/jiahao/Desktop/code/bbt_climb_plus/temp.py", line 7, in
>   
>       search('ipad2')   File "C:\Users\jiahao\Desktop\code\bbt_climb_plus\bbt_climb_plus\spiders\jingdong_spider.py",
>   line 194, in search
>       reactor.run() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1193,
>   in run
>       self.startRunning(installSignalHandlers=installSignalHandlers)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line
>   1173, in startRunning
>       ReactorBase.startRunning(self)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 684, in
>   startRunning
>       raise error.ReactorNotRestartable() twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable

The first search(keyword) succeeded, but the latter got wrong.

Could you help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Pawel Miech said

> In your code sample you are making calls to twisted.reactor starting
>   it on every function call. This is not working because there is only
>   one reactor per process and you cannot start it twice.

I found a way to solve my problem. Just using multiprocessing.

it will be like:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
def run_spider(keyword):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        p = Process(target=jingdong_spider.search, args=(keyword.encode('utf-8'),))
        p.start()
        p.join()
```

If everyone has problem in using python-multiprocessing. Better look at python documentation.

Comment: Although it's a dangling workaround, it works well. You've saved my day! I had 50 minutes to make my project work.

Comment: I got error.. `p.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 103, in start
'daemonic processes are not allowed to have children'
`

Answer (score 5):

In your code sample you are making calls to twisted.reactor starting it on every function call. This is not working because there is only one reactor per process and you cannot [start it twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910912/reactornotrestartable-when-launching-two-equivalent-unittest-with-twisted-and-tr).

There are two ways to solve your problem, both described in [documentation here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process). Either stick with `CrawlerRunner` but move `reactor.run()` outside your `search()` function to ensure it is only called once. Or use `CrawlerProcess` and simply call `crawler_process.start()`. Second approach is easier, your code would look like this:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from dirbot.spiders.dmoz import DmozSpider

def search(runner, keyword):
    return runner.crawl(DmozSpider, keyword)

runner = CrawlerProcess()
search(runner, "alfa")
search(runner, "beta")
runner.start()
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is awesome, but I need to use `search(keyword)` when I input something. i.e, `search(keyword)`need to be called when user do sth(like click button,etc).Such that `search(keyword)` can't hard-coded.   At last, I solve my problem with multiprocessing.

Comment: I am afraid I haven't explain clearly. `search(keyword)` may be called twice, triple, four times... It depends.

Comment: got error.. `processCrawl = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())` in some function, and when i called again it said `twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable`